# Is there a Japanese opening/intro for "Golden Boy" (「ゴールデンボーイ」)?

Tags: anime-history, golden-boy

"Golden Boy" (「ゴールデンボーイ」) op seems odd to me:

- There are shots of the main character with no credits on picture.
- The credits are white on a black background inter-titles inserted among the shots.
- The music is "unusual" and with no lyrics.

I must say that I watched it from a Spanish DVD edition (it included Spanish dub and subtitles).

The ending of the videos I watched are strange as well: just a classic white on black scroll with a Japanese song as sound.

Did "Golden Boy" aired in Japan with this kind of credits too? If so, is there a reason for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can gather, that is indeed the original opening. (Sorry, don't have the actual japanese release.)
According to [ANN](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=373) , the song is called *Golden Boy* and is by Joyo Katayanagi.

As to why it might seem a bit odd, well first off, the series came out in the mid-90s. While not standard, the stlye isn't exactly out of place for the time period.

Second off, keep in mind that the series **never aired on TV**, at least not at first. In stead it's an OVA (original video animation) and was first released on VHS and laserdisc. As such, it didn't really need to adhere to the usual TV-anime formats when it came to openings and such. As it was already guaranteed to have your attention, it pretty much just had to set the mood.

Also, it seems that the german release did get an opening with some lyrics. The song is called *My Golden Boy* by Computerjockeys. It's pretty much a remix of the original song with added english lyrics. The animation is still the same, tough.

Comment: Nice explanation about OVAs.

Comment: Thinking about your explanation, it does make a lot of sense since it simplifies the edition in different languages. BTW, I found the intro in [Japanese](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g5zk5GyGYJM), [Spanish](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qWkECvO-KDU) and [English](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5gFYhwuN5wc).